# JavaScript Click-Event trigger fires several times per click

Tags: javascript, html, onclicklistener

I have looked at similiar posts but I cant seem to find a Solution.

So the issue I am facing is that I dynamically add divs with content. If you click on that generated content, sth happens. Problem is that the clicklick Event fires several times. Interesting is, that it actually starts with only 1 trigger, goes up to 2,4,6,10,20,40 etc. triggers per click.

```
function AddArticle() {

    let single_article = document.createElement("div");
    single_article.setAttribute("class", "each-article");

    single_article = `<div> ANY ARTICEL </div>`;

    let prices_summary = document.getElementById('prices-summary');
    prices_summary.appendChild(single_article);

    //Refresh the Event since we added on DIV to the NodeList
    RefreshClickEvent();
}

function RefreshClickEvent() {

    let each_article = document.querySelectorAll(".each-article");

        for (let article of each_article ) {
            
            article.addEventListener('click', () => {

                console.log("Trigger.");
                
            });
        }
    }
```

```
Console Log OutPut: 
Trigger.
[2]Trigger.
[4]Trigger.
.
.
.
[90]Trigger.
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: share your HTML code

Comment: are you running the "AddArticle" method multiple times ? 
Because it will add a new event listener to each article. One optimization would be to add an event listener only to the parent node of your "articles".

Comment: For each element you're adding you're adding new listeners to _all_ the elements rather than just that one. Kevin is right. Use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).

Comment: Thanks everybody. That seems to be exactly the problem. Yes I am running AddArticle multiple times. I will try working with the parent or event delegation, now I know where to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an element, the loop in `RefreshClickEvent` works for all elements (including the elements that were added). So, you should define a parameter to add event to an element. Another mistake `innerHTML` to assign content.

```
function AddArticle() {

    let single_article = document.createElement("div");
    single_article.setAttribute("class", "each-article");

    single_article.innerHTML = `<div> ANY ARTICEL </div>`;

    let prices_summary = document.getElementById('prices-summary');
    prices_summary.appendChild(single_article);

    //Refresh the Event since we added on DIV to the NodeList
    RefreshClickEvent(single_article);
}

function RefreshClickEvent(element) {
        
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {

        console.log("Trigger.");
            
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks! How would you rather recommend me to assign content dynamically?

Comment: single_article.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true')